# Conditional statements with Dataframes [Julia v1.0]

Tags: julia

I am porting over custom functions from **R**. I would like to use Julia Dataframes to store my data. I like to reference by column name instead of, say, array indices hence I am using the Dataframes package.
I simplified the follow to illustrate:

```
if( DataFrame(x=1).x .>1) end
```

The error is:

> ERROR: TypeError: non-boolean (BitArray{1}) used in boolean context

Is there a simple workaround that would allow me to continue using DataFrames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression:

```
DataFrame(x=1).x .> 1
```

Does the following things:

1. Creates a `DataFrame`
2. Extracts a column `x` from it
3. Compares all elements of this column to `1` using vectorized operation `.>` (broadcasting in Julia parlance)

In effect you get the following one element array:

```
julia> DataFrame(x=1).x .> 1
1-element BitArray{1}:
 false
```

As opposed to R, Julia distinguishes between vectors and scalars so it is not the same as simply writing `false`. Moreover `if` statement expects a scalar not a vector, so something like this works:

```
if 2 > 1
    println("2 is greater than 1")
end
```

but not something like this:

```
if DataFrame(x=2).x .> 1
    println("success!")
end
```

However, for instance this would work:

```
if (DataFrame(x=2).x .> 1)[1]
    println("success!")
end
```

as you extract the first (and only in this case) element from the array.

Notice that in `R` if you passed more than one-element vector to a conditional expression you get a warning like this:

```
> if (c(T,F)) {
+ print("aaa") } else {print("bbb")}
[1] "aaa"
Warning message:
In
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Simply Julia is stricter than R in checking the types in this case. In R you do not have a distinction between scalars and vectors, but in Julia you have.

EDIT:

`length(df)` returns you the number of *columns* of a `DataFrame` (not number of rows). If you are coming from `R` it is easier to remember `nrow` and `ncol` functions.

Now regarding your question you can write either:

```
for i in 1:nrow(df)
    if df.x[i] > 3
        df.y[i] = df.x[i] + 1
    end
end
```

or

```
bigx = df.x .> 3
df.y[bigx] = df.x[bigx] .+ 1
```

or

```
df.y .= ifelse.(df.x .> 3, df.x .+ 1, df.y)
```

or using `DataFramesMeta` to shorten the notation:

```
using DataFramesMeta

@with df begin
    df.y .= ifelse.(:x .> 3, :x .+ 1, :y)
end
```

or

```
using DataFramesMeta

@byrow! df begin
    if :x > 3
        :y = :x + 1
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a very clear answer. I'd imagine that, in more ways than one, my self-taught R skills have led to me be quite sloppy.

Comment: In the instance that one had a column with several elements, should one nest the if statement within a for loop? e.g. `df = DataFrame(x=[2, 4], y = [0, 0])`
`for i in 1:length(df)
  if (df.x .> 3)[i]
  df.y[i] = df.x[i] +1
 end 
end
end`
 Or, would there be a more preferable approach?

Comment: I have presented you some options you could use. You might consider reviewing my tutorial on `DataFrames` here https://github.com/bkamins/Julia-DataFrames-Tutorial to get a general feeling how they can be used.

Comment: These options got me exactly where I was headed The ifelse example is brilliantly simple. Thank you again. And I will give your tutorial a thorough look.

Comment: Just note a `.` before `=` in `ifelse` example - this makes the whole expression work in-place, not allocate new vectors, and be essentially the same as a loop. The example with `bigx` is least efficient of all as it allocates new memory which would be relevant if you had a really big `DataFrame`.